# VLookup to get value is there is a match

Tags: excel, vlookup

When attempting this vlookup formula I am receiving #n/a how can I fix this. If a match is found in Column A then copy the address from Column B to Column F's matching user.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `VLOOKUP()` instead use `INDEX/MATCH()` combination. To ignore errors wrap the whole formula with `IFERROR()` function. Try-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$10,0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you match the columns "LogID" and "UserID", right? This could give you the values at "Match Result" ("F"). Well, for me doesn't make much sense not getting the result on the 2nd cell of "F", since there is a pair on "A". But for the first cell of "F", you will not receive any answer, since there is no "bb101" (UserID) on LogID

Comment: the match results column is an Example of what I am trying to achieve with vlookup instead of getting those results i am receiving #N/A

Comment: Thank for your first contribution. Only submit and answer if you will be providing a solution. If you are trying to gather more information, better use the comments on the original question.